# disable PHP stack trace

Tags: php

```
ini_set ( "log_errors", 1 );
ini_set ( "error_log", "/logs/error.log" );
ini_set ( "display_errors", 0 );
```

in error.log I got the Errors and a stack trace :

```
PHP Fatal error:  ...
PHP Stack trace:
1. ...
2. ...
3. ...
4. ...
```

I want disable stack trace to get only the 'PHP Fatal error' line

Comment: @hakre This is not a duplicate of 'Disable HTML stack traces by Xdebug'. The OP has not referred to XDebug in anyway. He wants to disable stack traces inherent in standard PHP error handling.

Answer (score -2):

This is most probably to be dealt with in the XDebug settings. You can disable stack traces using `xdebug_disable()`.

See the docs [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_disable)!