# Is there a way to stop Stack traces from being output with an Exception error?

Tags: php, error-handling, exception

I want to stop Stack Traces from appearing in my `fatal errors` in PHP.

My PHP code:

```
throw new ErrorException('Failed here!', 10);
```

Results in:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Failed here!' in C:\file\path\File.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sample-integrations\site-folder\index.php(18): Realex\Transaction::create(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\file\path\File.php on line 25

being output in the browser. How can I remove the stack trace?

Comment: `try {` your code and then `} catch(ErrorException $e) {` and catch it! `}`

Comment: Do you want to hide just the stacktrace? If so, why?

Comment: catching the exception ?

Comment: Error messages and stack traces are not for decoration purposes – they should help you to identify possible bugs in your code. What you are asking for sounds like cosmetic surgery. You should always print as much information as possible during development and suppress output of error messages on the production environment completely.

Comment: ^ hard disagree. Exception throwing is a control flow mechanism that is often used for error reporting but can be used for more complex control flow that has nothing to do with exceptional behavior. Extracting a specific payload from a thrown value is a perfectly acceptable line of inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been answered by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17766961/400114? Use the [xdebug_disable()](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_disable) function in the XDebug extension.

Not ideal, but might do the trick!